# How to keep a drop down menu open after redirect to subpage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I already spent now a few days searching and trying to solve this problem and could't find a solution.

I made a navigation-bar that has a subnavigation with toggle state and everything works well. But when a link is clicked and the page redirects to the sub-page I would like to keep the subnavigation opend and the actice tags in the navigation-bar and subnavigation-bar highlighted.

Here's my JS-Code:

```
(function($, undefined)
{
var open = [];
var opts = {
    selector: '.dropup',
    toggle: 'dropup-toggle',
    open: 'dropup-open',
    nest: true
};
$(document).on('click.dropup touchstart.dropup mouseenter.dropup', function(e)
{
    // Close the last open dropup if click is from outside the target dropup
    if ( open.length && ( ! opts.nest || ! open[ open.length - 1 ].find( e.target ).length ) )
    {
        open.pop().removeClass( opts.open );
    }
    var $this = $(e.target);
    // If target is a dropup then toggle it...
    if ( $this.hasClass( opts.toggle ) )
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        $this = $this.closest( opts.selector );
        if ( ! $this.hasClass( opts.open ) )
        {
            open.push( $this.addClass( opts.open ) );
        }
        else
        {
            open.pop().removeClass( opts.open );
        }
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/8vazthgv/

Any help is highly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: you can try using cookies and remind wich one was open when clicked on the link?

Comment: might consider adding the classes needed at server based on routing

Answer (score 0):

The script is removed from memory when the new page loads. You have two options:

1. Instead of loading a new page, load the content and put it into a `#content` DIV. That way, you never leave the current page. See [JQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)
2. Pass the last open menu to the new subpage as query parameters (i.e. the URL needs to look like `.../page.html?menu=foo&item=bar`. You can then examine those parameters from JavaScript and trigger the necessary events to open the menu.

Approach #1 is simpler and cleaner but for it to work, you need to redesign all the pages.

Approach #2 means you'll have to change the URLs (so they will look a bit ugly when the user looks at them).

Comment: url params aren't essential to make #2 work, not hard to match url to href

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by adding the navigation link hash to the sub page url like this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/l/explore/pages/events#explore

And then in the javascript, you can get the value of hash using location.hash and popup the submenu accordingly.

Comment: this div doesnt even exist. :P

Comment: I think you did not even understood the solution and commented and also downvoted, this is not about a div, it is about using the location.hash in javascript: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_loc_hash.asp

Comment: Thats ma bad there is a type its not div its the link you posted in your answer is not working

Answer (score 0):

Either use cookies or localStorage. Simple localStorage example in your case with be:

```
function saveMenuState(){
    var state = $('.dropup .dropup-open').attr('id');
    localStorage.setItem('menu-state', state);
}

function loadMenuState() {
    var state = localStorage.getItem('menu-state');
    if (state != null) $('#' + state).addClass('.dropup-open');
}

function resetMenuState() {
    localStorage.removeItem('menu-state');
}
```

Run `saveMenuState()` when opening a submenu. Run `loadMenuState()` when loading the page, possibly in your document ready function. Run `resetMenuState()`, when closing the submenus.